# Odds ratio and likelihood of A given B

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, observational-study

I've observed 500 nurses touching different surfaces during 500 episodes of patient care.

I've also recorded whether they wash their hands after they finish.

I'd like to find out if touching the patient makes it more likely (or has no influence) on hand hygiene. Is an Odds ratio the right statistical measure to use? And if so could you please point me in the right direction in calculating it?

Regards,
MF

Comment: The hypothesis to check would be that touching is independent of handwashing; the correct alternative to use is that touching and handwashing are dependent--*without specifying whether the dependency is a negative or positive one.* This places you in the simple, classical situation of analyzing a $2\times 2$ [contingency table.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=contingency+table+chi)

Comment: @whuber This seems logical. And then how does one deduce by how much patient contact affects or doesn't affect hygiene?

Comment: There are two issues: interpretation and estimation. These data do not allow you to support any conclusion that touching the patient "affects" hygiene. All you can possibly conclude is that the events are associated. (For instance, perhaps hygiene and touching are related because they stem from some innate quality in each nurse, not because the act of touching caused the nurse to wash hands.) Estimation amounts to computing the hand washing rates within each group: touched and did not touch. Confidence intervals are most readily obtained using @Kjetil's approach of logistic regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a logistic regression, then you are implicitely using oddsratios as the measure.  The parameter $\beta$ in a logistic regression is the log odds ratio.

To add some detail: let the index $i$ index the observations, so the covariable $x_i$  is the type of contact $i$, being a categorical variable, and $y_i=1$ if washing hands after contact $i$, zero contrarywise. Then logistic regression is the model:
$$
P(y_i=1 | x_i) = \frac{e^{\alpha+\beta x_i}}{1+e^{\alpha+\beta x_i}}
$$
Note that the equation must be read symbolically, the exact interpretation of the $\beta$s depend on the coding of $x$.  The most usual (recommended) coding:  If there are $k$ possible categories for $x$, then it is coded with $k-1$ dummys. The one category "left out" is the "reference category", and the $k-1$ $\beta$s express comparison with that left-out category. So each of those $\beta$s is an estimate of the log-oddsratio for the comparison of that category to the left-out one.

Comment: Could you clarify a little please? I've looked up the logistic regression so only just familiar with it. What will it really tell me? More than a simple probability P(Hand hygiene | Patient contact) ?

Comment: That sounds really good, thank you. I'm not sure how to categorise my $x$. I.e. I have for each observation: Patient contact= Yes or No, then Hand hygiene: Yes or No.

Comment: So you have only $k=2$ categories? Then you only need one dummy, so you can code patient contact yes=1, no=0.  If you usr software like R, the software will take care of construction of dummys.

Comment: I dont really understand how categories can be coded into this regression model. E.g. Imagine instead i have 5 surface groups: near patient, far from patient, patient, hygiene products, equipment. They are not like age groups of patients with or without a disease, which are sequential. I dont see how this fits.. Could you clarify please?